# How to setup db credentials for `sqlcmd` using a config file?

Tags: linux, sqlcmd

When I'm using `mysql` client, I can configure my db credentials in `~/.my.ini`.

How can I achieve similar thing with `sqlcmd` on Linux? Where and what filename I should create?

My goal is to avoid keep repeating hostname, user and passwords for every command.

Comment: If your goal is to avoid repeating, you can factorize the call with a generic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odbc.ini for mssql doesn't support the user and password.

`Server` parameter is used to specify port with syntax `[protocol:]Server[,port]`

Check `/etc/odbcinst.ini` for what driver name to use.

```
$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] # must match the 'Driver' in odbc.ini
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1
UsageCount=1

$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[ExampleDataSourceName]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Database=example_database_name
Server=tcp:10.1.2.3,50001

$ sqlcmd -D -S ExampleDataSourceName -U user
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL client is supporting [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/). So the credentials can be set in `odbc.ini` (e.g. `~/.odbc.ini`, `/etc/odbc.ini`). The configuration file can be also specified by `ODBCINI` environment variable.

Sample content:

```
[the_db]
    Description = The Database using MyODBC Driver DSN
    SERVER = localhost
    PORT =
    USER = root
    Password = somePassword
    Database = the_db
```

See: [Configuring and Testing iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/IODBCRubyHOWTO#Configuring%20and%20Testing%20iODBC).